# Linkedin login works fine on localhost but shows error on server

Tags: localhost, linkedin-api

I have attached Linkedin Signin function to a custom made button. While Ihost the code on localhost the signin works and all. But when someone tries to access the page by entering my IP and port number and tries to login they are getting an error. I am getting the same error. when I host the code on server and access the page.

[image: This is the error]

This is the code snippet.

```
   function liAuth(){
         IN.User.authorize(getProfileData());
         IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Most of the time sthe error can be removed by adding appropriate

Valid SDK Domains under javascript in your respective app in linkedin

developer app